# How url of laravel app under docker without "public"?

Tags: docker, laravel-5

Installing laravel 5.7 app under docker(based on php:7.2-apache ) I need to use "/public" in my url to run my app, so root url of my app is

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/public
```

I modified .env of my laravel app as

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8081/public/
```

But it did not help, as I browser I got image url :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/storage/mysites/-mysite-16/Babe_ver1.jpg?dt=1546059015
```

which way is invalid, as valid way must be :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/public/storage/mysites/-mysite-16/Babe_ver1.jpg?dt=1546059015
```

The similar way with ajax requests, as I got invalid ways :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/admin/get_activity_log_rows/1
```

But valid must be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/public/admin/get_activity_log_rows/1
```

In my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.1'

services:

web:

build:
context: ./web
dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml

environment:
- APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
volumes:
- ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
ports:
- 8081:80
working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}


composer:
image: composer:1.8
volumes:
- ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
command: composer install
```

and in .env of docker project :

```
# PATHS
DB_PATH_HOST=./databases
APP_PATH_HOST=./Mysites
APP_PTH_CONTAINER=/var/www/html/
```

How to set root url  of my site with “/public” ?

Thanks!

Comment: You posted the exact same question to https://forums.docker.com/t/how-url-of-laravel-app-under-docker-without-public/66027 and to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-set-url-of-laravel-app-under-docker-without-public?page=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look into option

```
ENTRYPOINT [“php”,“artisan”,“serve”,"–host=0.0.0.0","–port=your_app_port"]
```

in end of your Dockerfile.yml ?

OR :
Did you look at this https://github.com/petecoop/docker-laravel , with 000-default.conf defined, /public” path and other parameters were written ?